# How to force some database engine to understand SQL Server script files

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to export SQL schemas and SQL inserts (two SQL scripts) from SQL Server Studio in such way that at least one of `H2`, `HSQL`, `Derby` will be able to understand and execute it?

Answer (score 1):

(Probably) Not, for any arbitrary script.

Each Relational Database Management System (RDBMS) implements its own dialect of SQL. The chance of T-SQL (the SQL dialect implemented by SQL Server) being properly executed without tweaking on other RDBMS's is rather slim.

You can try it out and see where things go wrong and tweak the scripts yourself, or program something that modifies the scripts so that they can be executed on the RDBMS's you mention.